# Show all the data from table1 with matching records with table2 and show the result in to html table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql

[image]

As shown in Image I have 20 Records in `Table1` And 7 in `Table2` if I want to Show result like result table against UserID.

and show the result into view from database.
my view code is

```
<div class="tblContainer">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered  " id="TblRole" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>CreateAccess</th>
            <th>ViewAccess</th>
            <th>EditAccess</th>
            <th>ReportAccess</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

and I got the data in jsUsers script is

```
function SearchUser() {
    var EmpCode = $('#EmpCode').val()
    alert("Call");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Roles/GetUserRoleInformation",
        data: '{ EmpCode: "' + EmpCode + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.jsUsers != null) {

                alert("User Alredy Exist in FastTrack.");

                var rows;
                $.each(data.jsUsers, function (i, item) {
                    rows += "<tr>"
                              + "<td>" + item.RoleName + "</td>"
                              + "<td>" + item.CreateAccess + "</td>"
                              + "<td>" + item.ViewAccess + "</td>"
                              + "<td>" + item.EditAccess + "</td>"
                              + "<td>" + item.ReportAccess + "</td>"
                         + "</tr>";
                });
                $('#TblRole').append(rows);


            }
            else {
                alert("User Not Created yet.");

            }
        },

    });
}
```

Please Help to solve this problem.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.`UserID`, A.`RoleID`, A.`RoleName`, B.`Create`, B.`View`, B.`Edit`
FROM `Table1` A
LEFT JOIN `Table2` B ON A.`RoleID` = B.`RoleID` AND B.`UserID` = 1
```

**Updated Answer:**

Simply use your input value as `UserID`:

```
SELECT 1 AS `UserID`, A.`RoleID`, A.`RoleName`, B.`Create`, B.`View`, B.`Edit`
FROM `Table1` A
LEFT JOIN `Table2` B ON A.`RoleID` = B.`RoleID` AND B.`UserID` = 1
```

Otherwise if you pass the `UserId` as `parameter`.

Then use the parameter:

```
SELECT @ParamValue AS `UserID`, A.`RoleID`, A.`RoleName`, B.`Create`, B.`View`, B.`Edit`
FROM `Table1` A
LEFT JOIN `Table2` B ON A.`RoleID` = B.`RoleID` AND B.`UserID` = @ParamValue
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. Above solution Is correct but in UserID column Shows the null value i need to show all the value as per UserID. please see the Image